# Explicação de código JQUERY/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu precisava fazer um sistema de upload, que ao selecionar a imagem, uma preview seria mostrada em uma box antes de ser enviada. 
Vi um código aqui no Stackoverflow e tentei adaptá-lo.
Gostaria de saber se ele está semanticamente correto, de acordo com as normas da língua, e também, gostaria de uma explicação sobre o código. (não manjo de JQUERY/JS).

Agradeço a todos que ajudarem :)
Bom fim de semana

```js
$('.arquivo').change(function(){
    var preview = $('.enviar_screenshot button'); //BOTAO DE SELECIONAR ARQUIVO
    var file    = $('.arquivo')[0].files[0]; // O ARQUIVO
    var reader  = new FileReader(); 
    var ext = ['jpg','jpeg','png']; // EXTENSÕES PERMITIDAS
    var extArquivo = file.name.split(".").pop(); //PEGA A EXTENSÃO DO ARQUIVO

    reader.onloadend = function () {

     if(typeof ext.find(function(extt){return extArquivo == extt; }) == 'undefined') { // VERIFICA SE A EXTENSÃO NÃO É VÁLIDA, SE NÃO, REALIZA O PROCESSO NORMAL
           $(preview).css({'background-image':'none', 'opacity':'1'});
         $(preview).html('<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>');
       } else {
         $(preview).css({'background-image':'url(' + reader.result + ')', 'background-size':'cover', 'background-position':'center', 'opacity':'0.5'});
       }

     
    }

    if (file) { // MOSTRA
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      $(preview).text("");
    } else {
     $(preview).css({'background-image':'none', 'opacity':'1'});
     $(preview).html('<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o código abaixo recebe a imagem do input-image, valida se o tipo da imagem é permitido, e realiza a alteração da imagem na div de pré visualização da mesma, o envio da imagem via javascript precisa ser feito via POST (pode ser com ajax) aqui está um algo que posso te ajudar a implementar isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image

Então basicamente, agora só basta implementar o método de POST para o servidor, pois o de pré-visualização já está implementado.

Se desejar, pode fazer o POST normalmente através da ação submit do próprio HTML5, e fazer o restante do processo com a linguagem de backend, é uma forma mais simples mas pode não atender bem dependendo da sua necessidade.

```js
$('.arquivo').change(function(){
    var preview = $('.enviar_screenshot button'); //BOTAO DE SELECIONAR ARQUIVO
    var file    = $('.arquivo')[0].files[0]; // O ARQUIVO
    var reader  = new FileReader(); 
    var ext = ['jpg','jpeg','png']; // EXTENSÕES PERMITIDAS
    var extArquivo = file.name.split(".").pop(); //PEGA A EXTENSÃO DO ARQUIVO

    reader.onloadend = function () {

     if(typeof ext.find(function(extt){return extArquivo == extt; }) == 'undefined') { // VERIFICA SE A EXTENSÃO NÃO É VÁLIDA, SE NÃO, REALIZA O PROCESSO NORMAL
           $(preview).css({'background-image':'none', 'opacity':'1'});
         $(preview).html('<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>');
       } else {
         $(preview).css({'background-image':'url(' + reader.result + ')', 'background-size':'cover', 'background-position':'center', 'opacity':'0.5'});
       }

     
    }

    if (file) { // MOSTRA
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      $(preview).text("");
    } else {
     $(preview).css({'background-image':'none', 'opacity':'1'});
     $(preview).html('<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>');
    }
 });
```

Comment: O backend já está pronto e funcionando, eu só gostaria de saber se o código estava correto mesmo, pois não manjo muito.  Mas obrigado :)